# Getting an error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state') in vuejs while using Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I am trying to learn vuex and following tutorials on youtube for vuex, I am in a error of
**TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')**, where I am not able figure out why I am getting this error , I assume it might be because of the newer version not sure.
Here is my code:
TodoList.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>Todo list</h4>
    <todo
      v-for="(task, index) in $store.state.todos" // getting error here
      :key="index"
      :todo="todo"
    ></todo>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Todo from "./Todo.vue";
export default {
  name: "TodoList",
  components: { Todo },
  computed: {},
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

here is my
store/index.js

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex';

export const store = createStore({
    state: {
        todos: [{
                title: 'Task 1',
                completed: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Task 2',
                completed: false
            }
        ]
    }
    // other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

mapState is a helper that simplifies creating a computed property that reflects the value of a given state

You can access your data like below:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h4>Todo list</h4>
    <todo
      v-for="(task, index) in todos" 
      :key="index"
      :todo="todo"
    ></todo>
  </div>
</template>


import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  data: {},

  computed: {
   ...mapState({
    todos: state => state.todos
   })
  }
}
```